# Unable to extract the checkbox value - Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Used dictionary to generate a list of variables and assign them their type.
Then extracted the variables into a list that could be used for checkbox in tkinter.
Now I would like to extract the value stored in the variables.
How may I do that?

Cause the way I tried it - at the print(var_list[x].get()) - I get an error.
It says "str" object has no attribute "get"

```
for number in range(len(checklist_prt)):    
            a_dictionary["vari{0}".format(number)] = StringVar()
            #CREATING A LIST TO USE VARIABLES
            var_list=list(a_dictionary.keys()) 
            row_num.append(number)
            

    for x in range(len(checklist_prt)):
        button_1_checklist_1=Checkbutton(checklist_part,text=checklist_prt[x],variable=var_list[x])
        button_1_checklist_1.deselect()
        button_1_checklist_1.grid(row=row_num[x],column=0,sticky='w')

def vlu():

    for x in range(len(checklist_prt)):
        print(var_list[x].get())
        

values=Button(checklist_part,text="Vlu",command=vlu)
values.grid(row=len(checklist_prt)+1,column=0,sticky='w')
```

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and especially not links to pictures of code or errors. Instead, create a [mcve].

Comment: Bryan, Understood. Hope this makes it a bit better.

Comment: `var_list` is your list of keys from `a_dictionary` and will just be the strings you put there. And the error is telling you that strings don't have a get method. I think you meant it to have the values not the keys. -- really I am not even sure what you were trying to do...

Comment: @AndrewAllaire In that first section of the code all I'm trying to do is generate a list that contains variables of type StringVar(). That can be used for the checkbutton widget in the next block of code.

Comment: Change `var_list=list(a_dictionary.keys())` to `var_list=list(a_dictionary.values())`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set a tkinter String variable for both key and value.

```py
for number in range(len(checklist_prt)):    
            key = StringVar()
            key.set("vari{0}".format(number))
            a_dictionary[key] = StringVar()
            #CREATING A LIST TO USE VARIABLES
            var_list=list(a_dictionary.keys()) 
            row_num.append(number)
            

    for x in range(len(checklist_prt)):
        button_1_checklist_1=Checkbutton(checklist_part,text=checklist_prt[x],variable=var_list[x])
        button_1_checklist_1.deselect()
        button_1_checklist_1.grid(row=row_num[x],column=0,sticky='w')

def vlu():

    for x in range(len(checklist_prt)):
        print(var_list[x].get())
        

values=Button(checklist_part,text="Vlu",command=vlu)
values.grid(row=len(checklist_prt)+1,column=0,sticky='w')
```

Please note by the way that you do not require that 0 in your `format`ed string.